# How to see file from docker for Windows host on a running container and vice versa

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get a Linux container to share files with the Windows host, primarily because I want to build some Linux libs, and put the resulting output where I can see them in the file system. I open a cmd.exe window and do the following.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1565]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\alanmur>mkdir \dev\test

C:\Users\alanmur>cd \dev\test

C:\dev\test>echo for the container >> testfile.out

C:\dev\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0C3F-DCE2

 Directory of C:\dev\test

2020-01-07  21:45    <DIR>          .
2020-01-07  21:45    <DIR>          ..
2020-01-07  21:45                20 testfile.out
               1 File(s)             20 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  52,950,069,248 bytes free

C:\dev\test>docker run -it --rm -v C:/dev/test:/app/data:rw alpine /bin/sh
/ # cd /app/data
/app/data # ls
/app/data # echo for the host >> testfile2.out
/app/data # ls
testfile2.out
/app/data # exit

C:\dev\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0C3F-DCE2

 Directory of C:\dev\test

2020-01-07  21:45    <DIR>          .
2020-01-07  21:45    <DIR>          ..
2020-01-07  21:45                20 testfile.out
               1 File(s)             20 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  52,942,929,920 bytes free

C:\dev\test>
```

How would I set this up so that the first `ls` on the container shows testfile.out and then when I exit the container I can see testfile2.out in the host C:\dev\test directory? I swear I had this working before, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong now, as I am doing everything the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't done is with this particular location/drive. You need to allow docker to access it.

## Here is how (for windows)

For you it is drive C:

> In the System Tray, you should have the
> cute Docker whale swimming. Right click and select Settings.
>
> Docker Settings Menu
>
> 2. In the Settings dialog that comes up, click on Shared Drives. This should be able to list down the drives that you have available on your
>    Windows machine. In my case, I have C and D drives and I have chosen
>    to share D:\ drive since I want to expose the D:\data folder to my
>    containers.
>
> Docker for Windows : Shared Drives
> 3. Click on Apply. This will bring up the Credentials dialog and you will need to provide your current Windows credentials. Ensure that you
> give it correctly. I also suspect that you might need to be an
> Administrator.

Source: https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: I had seen the shared folder, and it still appeared to be shared. However, **my password had changed** and I needed to reset/update the credentials. This involved clicking 'Reset Credentials' in the settings/shared drive tab, which unshared the drive, then sharing it again by clicking the box and entering the new password. Then everything works. Thank you for your help!